# Turning R list into matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list that is structured similar to the list below.

**Example List**

```
    [[1]]
     [1] "Header A1"         
     [2] "Header A2"                                     
     [3] ""                                                
     [4] "Name A1"                             
     [5] "Address A1"                            
     [6] "Phone A1"                           
     [7] "Web A1"                          
     [8] ""                                                
     [9] "Header B1"                                           
    [10] "Header B2"                              
    [11] ""                                                
    [12] "Address B1"                              
    [13] "Address B2"                           
    [14] "Phone B1"                           
    [15] "Web B1"                
    [16] ""                                                
    [17] "Header C1"                       
    [18] "Header C2"                               
    [19] ""                                                
    [20] "Address C1"                                
    [21] "Address C2"                              
    [22] "Phone C1"                           
    [23] "Web C1"         
    [24] ""                                                
    [25] "Header D1"                                       
    [26] "Header D2"                     
    [27] ""                                                
    [28] "Address D1"                              
    [29] "Phone D1"                           
    [30] "Web D1"
    [31] ""                                                
    [32] "Header E1"                                       
    [33] "Header E2"                     
    [34] ""                                                
    [35] "Address E1"                              
    [35] "Address E1" 
    [35] "Address E1" 
    [36] "Phone E1"                           
    [37] "Web E1"
    [38] ""
```

I need a way to convert this list in R to a matrix.  The final matrix would be something like this.  The blank elements indicate where the rows will split.  In this case there are blanks at 3, 8, 11, 16, 19, 24, 27, 31, 34, 38.  However the rows will split at 8,16, 24,31 , 38 (consistently every other blank element). And the number of elements that go into each row is not consistent, it does need to be transformed into rows based on where those second blanks are. The end result would then be...

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Header A1 | Header A2 | Name A1 | Address A1 | Phone A1 | Web A1 |  |
| Header B1 | Header B2 | Address B1 | Address B2 | Phone B1 | Web B1 |  |
| Header C1 | Header C2 | Address C1 | Address C2 | Phone A1 | Web A1 |  |
| Header D1 | Header D2 | Address D1 | Phone D1 | Web D1 |  |  |
| Header E1 | Header E2 | Address E1 | Address E2 | Address E3 | Phone E1 | Web E1 |

Any advice on how to do this programmatically in R would be much appreciated! Thank you.

```
    list(c("Header A1", "Header A2", "", "Name A1", "Address A1", 
    "Phone A1", "Web A1", "", "Header B1", "Header B2", "", "Address B1", 
    "Address B2", "Phone B1", "Web B1", "", "Header C1", "Header C2", 
    "", "Address C1", "Address C2", "Phone C1", "Web C1", "", "Header D1", 
    "Header D2", "", "Address D1", "Phone D1", "Web D1", "", "Header E1", 
    "Header E2", "", "Address E1", "Address E2", "Address E3", "Phone E1", 
    "Web E1", ""))
```

Comment: Could you please paste the list into the question with the output of `dput(your_list)`. This will make the question reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

data.frame(val = dat_ls[[1]]) |> 
  mutate(group = row_number() %/% 8,
         col_id = paste0("col", row_number() %% 8))|> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = col_id, values_from = val) |> 
  select(-c(group, col3, col0)) |>
  rename(col3 = col4, col4 = col5, col5 = col6, col6 = col7) |> 
  as.matrix()
#>      col1        col2        col3         col4         col5       col6    
#> [1,] "Header A1" "Header A2" "Name A1"    "Address A1" "Phone A1" "Web A1"
#> [2,] "Header B1" "Header B2" "Address B1" "Address B2" "Phone B1" "Web B1"
#> [3,] "Header C1" "Header C2" "Address C1" "Address C2" "Phone C1" "Web C1"
#> [4,] "Header D1" "Header D2" "Address D1" "Phone D1"   "Web D1"   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

data

```
dat_ls <- list(c("Header A1", "Header A2", "", "Name A1", "Address A1", 
                 "Phone A1", "Web A1", "", "Header B1", "Header B2", "", "Address B1", 
                 "Address B2", "Phone B1", "Web B1", "", "Header C1", "Header C2", 
                 "", "Address C1", "Address C2", "Phone C1", "Web C1", "", "Header D1", 
                 "Header D2", "", "Address D1", "Phone D1", "Web D1"))
```